# How to programmatically change the friendly name of a Windows audio device?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, audio, driver

What is the proper API call that I should use to rename an audio device on windows? My goal is to change the device name that is shown to the user when they right click the volume icon and select "playback devices." I believe "friendly name" is the property I want to alter.

I've managed to successfully call [SetupDiSetDeviceProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552163(v=vs.85).aspx), which returns true. If I subsequently call [SetupDiGetDeviceProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551963(v=vs.85).aspx), the recently set value is returned. However, this value seems to only exist within the context of my application - the system setting seems unchanged.

Is there another function call that I should call instead of or in addition to `SetupDiSetDeviceProperty`?

I have been running my application as an administrator, so permissions shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I don't know how using those APIs, but if you can rename the device via Explorer then would be able to use the shell to do it. Bind to the appropriate folder, identify the item and call `IShellFolder::SetNameOf`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. There are no file system objects on my machine with a name containing the friendly name of my audio devices. What are you suggesting I rename?

Comment: It would be in one of the control panel folders, which are accessible via the shell interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will allow you to change it, but according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316587(v=vs.85).aspx): 
(msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316587(v=vs.85).aspx)

PKEY_DeviceInterface_FriendlyName

The PKEY_DeviceInterface_FriendlyName property contains the friendly name of the audio adapter to which the endpoint device is attached (for example, "XYZ Audio Adapter").

The vt member of the PROPVARIANT structure is set to VT_LPWSTR.
The pwszVal member of the PROPVARIANT structure points to a null-terminated, wide-character string that contains the friendly name.
Requirements

Minimum supported client - Windows Vista [desktop apps only]
Minimum supported server - Windows Server 2008 [desktop apps only]

Header - Functiondiscoverykeys_devpkey.h